# Adding characters to the end of a line using SED

Tags: sed

I am trying to add there exclamation points to the end of each line in this text file. I was told I need to switch all characters from lower case to upper case and have done so with string below. I am not sure how to incorporate the exclamation points in the same `sed` statement.

```
cat "trump.txt" | sed 's/./\U&/g'
```

Comment: You want to match `.*` (the whole line) instead of `.` (a single character) - then you can just add the exclamation marks at the end of the substitution. And `g` won't be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this sample text:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
this is a sample text
Another line
3 apples
```

With `sed` command given in question which uppercases one character at a time with `g` flag

```
$ sed 's/./\U&/g' ip.txt 
THIS IS A SAMPLE TEXT
ANOTHER LINE
3 APPLES
```

To add some other characters at end

```
$ sed 's/.*/\U&!!!/' ip.txt 
THIS IS A SAMPLE TEXT!!!
ANOTHER LINE!!!
3 APPLES!!!
```

- `.*` will match entire line and `&` will contain entire line while replacing
- `g` flag is not needed as substitution is happening only once

Answer (score 1):

Here is `awk` version , where all the text will be converted into uppercase and then three exclamations would be added.

```
 awk '{$0=toupper($0) "!!!"}1' input
 THIS IS A SAMPLE TEXT!!!
 ANOTHER LINE!!!
 3 APPLES!!!
```

Explanation:
`$0` is entire line or record. `toupper` is an `awk` inbuilt function to convert input to uppercase. Here `$0` is provided as input to toupper function. So, it will convert `$0` to uppercase.finally uppercased `$0` and `!!!` would be substituted to $0 as new values.

Breakdown of the command:

```
awk '{$0=toupper($0)}1' input # to make text uppercase.  
awk '{$0= $0 "!!!"}1' input   # to add "`!!!`" in the end of text.
```

Or `bash` way: `^^` sign after variable name will make contents of variable uppercase.

```
while read line;
   do
   echo "${line^^}"'!!!' ;
done <input
```